# Netbeans cannot connect to MySQL server that is on MAMP

Tags: mysql, netbeans, mamp

After I have put in all correct information for Netbeans to connect to MySQL server on my MAMP (port:8889), I'm getting:

"Unable to connect to the MySQL server:

org.netbeans.api.db.explorer.DatabaseException: org.netbeans.api.db.explorer.DatabaseException: java.sql.SQLException: null,  message from server: "Host '172.16.151.134' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server".

The server may not be running or your MySQL connection properties may not be set correctly.  Do you want to edit your MySQL connection properties?"

After some research, I found that some users were able to solve this issue by unchecking allow only local connection on MAMP PRO, but I do not have access to MAMP PRO anymore and MAMP does not offer such feature. What files do I need to modify to allow Netbeans to connect to MySQL server on MAMP?

Answer (score 1):

Under MAMP, in the MySQL tab, Uncheck the following "Allow local access only".
This should make netbeans connect to mysql.